# Как установить значение textarea (TinyMce) с помощью jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce, textarea

Как установить значение textarea(TinyMce editor) с помощью jQuery

html:

```
<td colspan="11"><div id="112" class="sp_comm"><p>TEST2222</p></div></td>
<textarea style="width: 100%; display: none;" cols="100" rows="5" name="elm" id="elm11" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.sp_comm').dblclick(function () {
    var sp_val = $(this).html();
    var sp_id = $(this).attr('id');
    sp_id = parseInt((sp_id / 10), 10);

    alert(sp_val + ',id:' + sp_id);
    $('#elm11').html('TTT');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tinymce.get('mceeditor_'+id).setContent(ajax_str);
```

[ENG SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094094/tinymce-setcontent-dynamically-jquery-added-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#elm11').val('TTT');
```

- начать, хотя бы, с этого. Только так значение textarea задается при помощи javascript. Про HTML забудьте.